# SharedPreferences not working ("Cannot resolve method 'getPreferences' ")

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm currently trying to save a simple integer value from an EditText to sharedPreferences so that I can access it within any activity. I've tried following the google tutorials but I was unable to make it work. I ended up getting the error message "Cannot resolve method 'getPreferences' ". I realize that there have been other threads about sharedPreferences but I cannot seem to make sense of them.

Also, if you can help me find a better way than my catch statement to avoid the NumberFormatException, please let me know. Thanks again!Any help is much appreciated!

Java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.managergmail.time.finite.finitemanager02.R.id.textViewTest;


public class ExamPrepHome extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exam_prep_home);

    Button buttonSaveNumberOfExams = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveNumberOfExams);


    try{
           final  EditText numberOfExamsInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberOfExamsInput);
           final int numberOfExamsValue = Integer.valueOf(numberOfExamsInput.getText().toString());


           buttonSaveNumberOfExams.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_number_of_exams), numberOfExamsValue);
                        editor.commit();
                    }

                });

           }catch(NumberFormatException ex){

                System.out.println("Value at TextView is not a valid integer");

            }



}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of 
`SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
use `SharedPreferences sharedPref = ExamPrepHome.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Reason for this is because inside the anonymous class, 'this' represents that inner class and not the Activity object. And you have to use number format exception to check to avoid crashes when you retrieve the object.

Comment: I need to wait a minute before it will let me accept